# Three monitors supported on NVIDIA card?

Tags: xorg, nvidia

I have a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 460 and have been trying to figure out if it has three monitor support.

I tried plugging in three monitors and the card does pick all three up. After I set them up, save the xorg.conf file and restart, only two of them come up active. I've tried looking around the web to see if maybe it only supports two.

Anyone have more info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope you can only use two monitors per Nvidia card.

Even in Windows you're limited to two per card. The only exception to this is the latest GTX590 which, technically speaking, is two cards in one.

---

**Edit:** This seems like it might be changing in the newest Nvidia hardware (higher Kepler chipsets). Do not own so cannot confirm for certain but reports suggest you can connect and drive four monitors at once.

I've no idea whether the binary driver supports this. I don't know if nouveau supports this.

Comment: Does it make sense that it sees all three monitors in the Nvidia settings thing?

Comment: oh. and one more question. can I use the builtin port on my motherboard as a third port? and if so, do you know how?

Comment: @johannix No it doesn't make sense but it doesn't make sense to the point where I think it should work. You *can* use another video card at the same time **but** when you split across multiple GPUs, strange things can happen. You wont, for example, be able to shift 3d content around. Might be worth a go. Here's [a fairly old forum post with a starting point for you](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6659614&postcount=8). Or test a cheap AMD/ATI card that does support three screens. IIRC you can get them for under £50.