# Configuration for three display setup with two Nvidia cards?

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, xorg, xubuntu, multiple-monitors

I have two video adapters: `NVIDIA GeForce GTX 570` and a three LCD displays connected to them.

Here's the topology illustrated graphically:

```
[ GTX 570 ]  === HDMI ===> Philips 273ELH  #0  (CENTER/MAIN)
[         ]  ==== DVI ===> DELL P1913      #2  (RIGHT)

[ GTX 570 ]  ==== DVI ===> DELL P1913      #1  (LEFT, PORTRAIT)
```

And a physical layout:

```
[      ]  [              ]  [         ]
[ #1   ]  [      #0      ]  [   #2    ]
[      ]  [              ]  [         ]
[      ]  [              ]
```

I've managed to place all displays correctly by using `xorg.conf`, [here's my version](https://gist.github.com/slavafomin/7b97edc6f7813b39abaf#file-xorg-conf), but I can't move windows between displays. They are somehow isolated from each other.

I'm using proprietary NVIDIA driver version `331.38`, because I'm experiencing some rendering problems with Nouveau (especially with Guake) and as far as I understand proprietary drivers should have a better performance.

I know I can use `Xinerama`, but I'm getting a lot of glitches and strange behavior with it (especially in [Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469994/google-chrome-black-screen-in-xubuntu-14-04)).

Is it possible to create continuous desktop space without using `Xinerama` or to configure `Xinerama` to work correctly without all those glitches?

Thank you!

Comment: See [Three monitors supported on NVIDIA card?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33813/three-monitors-supported-on-nvidia-card) and [Nvidia How do I get three monitors working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21144/nvidia-how-do-i-get-three-monitors-working)

Comment: @bain, thank you for your response! But I can't find an answer to my question in those posts.

Comment: Try this one [How can I get xrandr to detect both nvidia cards: 2 x GTX480, triple-head?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123862/how-can-i-get-xrandr-to-detect-both-nvidia-cards-2-x-gtx480-triple-head) (and from that link [Enabling a triple-head (3 monitor) setup on Linux Mint 16 (“Petra”) with two Nvidia cards](https://www.martineve.com/2014/04/15/enabling-a-triple-head-3-monitor-setup-on-linux-mint-16-petra-with-two-nvidia-cards/))